# XOR in Racket, I dont understand how it works

Tags: scheme, racket, boolean-logic, xor

```
(define xor
  (lambda (x y) 
    (if (boolean=? x y) 
        #f 
        #t)))
```

How does it work?
I don't understand that

Comment: Well...since I've never seen Racket code before (looks like LISP), and given the traditional definition of XOR = `x && !y || !x && y`...then it seems like it'd work (since I would assume that `boolean=?` would check for both being true - and I might be horribly wrong on that).

Comment: You may wish to read the [SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to improve your question. It will be difficult to answer your question without knowing what you've tried, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at [`xor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)'s [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table):

```
x xor y
T  F  T             ; x and y are both true,  x xor y is false
T  T  F             ; x and y are different,  x xor y is true
F  T  T             ; x and y are different,  x xor y is true
F  F  F             ; x and y are both false, x xor y is false
```

In other words: if both `x` and `y` are equal, then `xor` is false. But if `x` and `y` are different, then `xor` is true. And that's exactly what this Scheme code says:

```
(if (boolean=? x y) ; are x and y equal?
  #f                ; then xor is false
  #t)               ; otherwise xor is true
```